# Problem with firebase Realtime Databe remove child from children with a specific value using kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table named “Notificaciones” in Realtime Database. I need to remove a specific value from a child any time it is in a another child. It’s better you look at the picture to understand because It’s hard to explain using words [image]

I’ve tried everything but I don’t know how to erase just the children with those values. I've searched similar questions here but my table it's too specific to know how to use them.
I've added code but nothing seem to work

```
  val refNotificaciones = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Notificaciones")
                        refNotificaciones.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
                        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.exists())
                                for(snapshot in snapshot.children) {
                                var notificacion = snapshot.getValue(Notificacion::class.java)
                                if (notificacion.idPublicacion == "-NQR3BcakgyZgGT6zu2b") {
                                    snapshot.ref.removeValue()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        }
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's actually not possible with your actual database structure. All queries in the Realtime Database work on a flat list of nodes, where the value that you need to get, must exist at a **fixed** path under each direct child node.

Unfortunately, that's not your case, because you have a dynamic key under the "Notificaciones" node, which is actually the UID. Besides that, each user object contains multiple objects that are added using push IDs.

It's true that you can attach the listener on the "Notificaciones" node, as you already do, download the data in memory and perform the filter on the client, but that isn't practical at all. So in your case, such a schema doesn't help.

If you want to remove all children within all notifications of all users when the `idPublicacion` holds a specific value, then you should consider denormalizing the data. So you should create another node, that should contain all notifications of all users.

```
db
|
--- allNotifications
      |
      --- -NQR3...zuub
      |     |
      |     --- //fields
      |
      --- -NQR3...4RII
      |     |
      |     --- //fields
      |
      --- -NQR3...d9hU
            |
            --- //fields
```

In this way, you'll only have a single dynamic level in your database, and a query like the one below:

```
db.child("allNotifications").whereEqualTo("idPublicacion", "-NQR3BcakgyZgGT6zu2b")
```

Will work perfectly fine. But remember, you'll always have to keep both nodes in sync, meaning that if a new child is added under the first node, add it to the second. That's the same in case of an update or a delete operation.

Comment: Hey Monrac. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hi. Sorry I'm out from home I'll chek it in a week when I'll came back!!!

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.  Thanks.